# value of len(sys.argv)'s posing problems

Tags: python-3.x, cs50, sys

So I'm trying to use the value of `sys.argv` to get a font for the `input` to be printed in. But sys.argv's value remains `1` no matter how many values I type in the terminal.

the first `if` works great, but the code never reaches`elif`part even if I type`filename.py value1 value2`

Here's my code:

```
import pyfiglet
import sys
import random

from pyfiglet import Figlet
figlet = Figlet()

#for fonts
fonts_chosen = figlet.getFonts()
font_ = (random.choice(["3-d", "3x5", "5lineoblique", "acrobatic"]))

if len(sys.argv) == 1 :
    str = input("Input: ")
    figlet.setFont(font=font_)
    print(figlet.renderText(str))
elif len(sys.argv) == 3 :
    if sys.argv[1] == "-f" or sys.argv[1] == "--font":
        if sys.argv[2] == fonts_chosen:
            str = input("Input: ")
            figlet.setFont(font=sys.argv[2])
            print(figlet.renderText(str))
        else:
            sys.exit("Invalid usage")
    else:
        sys.exit("Invalid usage")
else:
    sys.exit("Invalid usage")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a logical flaw. In `if sys.argv[2] == fonts_chosen` you are comparing your input argument to a whole list which you declared in `fonts_chosen = figlet.getFonts()` (considering you didn't provide that big list in your argument). We can update it with `if sys.argv[2] in fonts_chosen`, that way our argument will be checked whether it belongs to that list of fonts or not.

Here is the updated code, where you don't need two arguments as one will suffice. Moreover, during random choice, you can provide the `fonts_chosen` list to get the font selected randomly from the list rather than the 4 you provided.

```py
import pyfiglet
import sys
import random

from pyfiglet import Figlet
figlet = Figlet()

#for fonts
fonts_chosen = figlet.getFonts()
font_ = (random.choice(["3-d", "3x5", "5lineoblique", "acrobatic"]))


if len(sys.argv) == 1 :
    str = input("Input: ")
    figlet.setFont(font=font_)
    print(figlet.renderText(str))
elif len(sys.argv) == 2 :
    if sys.argv[1] in fonts_chosen:
        str = input("Input: ")
        figlet.setFont(font=sys.argv[1])
        print(figlet.renderText(str))
    else:
        sys.exit("Invalid font, please provide a valid font name")
else:
    sys.exit("Invalid usage, provide a single argument i.e. font name or you can run it without an argument")
```